# Linear model and mean value of covariates

Tags: multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, leverage

Suppose a linear model $$Y_i=\beta_0+x_{i1}\beta_1+\ldots+x_{ip}\beta_p+e_i,\quad e_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2),\quad i=1,\ldots,n,$$ and its hat matrix $P=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$, where $Y=X\beta+e$.

Let $\bar{x}_{i\cdot}=(1/p)\sum_{j=1}^p x_{ij}$. Then we can write a new linear model: $$Y_i=\gamma_0+(x_{i1}-\bar{x}_{i\cdot})\gamma_1+\ldots+(x_{ip}-\bar{x}_{i\cdot})\gamma_p+e_i,\quad e_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2),\quad i=1,\ldots,n.$$Call the new hat matrix $\hat{P}$. Is it true that $P=\hat{P}$? What is the mathematical proof?

Comment: Is this self study?

Comment: You can try to write new model as $Y = \hat{X}\beta + \epsilon$ where $\hat{X} = XA$ for some full rank matrix $A$

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad Yes, this is self-study. I am studying these models at university but from a practical point of view, and I would like to understand all formulas theoretically.

Comment: Then I hope you will find my hint useful

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad I was thinking and the thing is that I want to write the new model as $Y=\hat{X}\gamma+\epsilon$ (not $\hat{X}\beta+\epsilon$, so that it continues having an intercept). In that case I cannot see why $\hat{X}=XA$ (how can I go from $X$ to $\hat{X}$ by elementary transformations of the columns of $X$?)

Comment: You have inconsistent notations. If you write $$Y = X\beta + \epsilon$$ then you assume that first column of $X$ are all $1$'s, i.e. you have $X = [\vec{1}, X_1]$, where $\vec{1} = [1,\dots,1]^T$, and $\beta = [\beta_0, \vec{\beta_1}]$. Thus you probably wanted the mean to be $\bar{x}_i = \frac{1}{p+1} 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{p} x_{i,j}$

Comment: As for the matrix $A$. Suppose that you have $O = \frac{1}{p+1}[\vec{1}, \dots, \vec{1}]$ (matrix with only $1$'s), what is $XO$? How can you zero the first column of matrix $XO$?